# Add contacts to an MS outlook Appointment

Tags: java, ms-office, outlook-2007, appointment

I have created a java program to create appointment on MS Outlook.

```
setProperty(appointment, "Subject", "Meeting");
```

here the "Subject" is the tag which uses to set a subject for the appointment.

Now I want to add some contacts to the appointment. So like the "Subject" tag there should be some tags to add contact name, Mob Number and email to an appointment.

Can any one help me to find out those tags please?

Thanks in advance.. :)